# (Retool) Make a ".txt" file to GCS but I got the error "Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded."

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, retool, google-cloud-storage

On **Retool**, I'm trying to make a **".txt"** file with some words to **Google Cloud Storage(GCS)** but I got **this error**.

[image]

> makeTXTFile: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be
> decoded is not correctly encoded.

This is the **query settings** on **Retool** to make a **".txt"** file to **GCS**:

[image]

**Action type** and **Content-Type**:

[image]

**Upload file name**:

[image]

**Upload data**:

[image]

```js
Lemon
Banana
Pineapple
```

And I want the **".txt"** file with **a fruit name in each row** as **below**:

[image]

Are there any ways to make the **".txt"** file from **Retool** to **GCS** without the **error**?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **encode the string** in **Base64** with **"btoa()"** method and the **string** needs to have **"\n"** for **line break**:

[image]

```js
{{ btoa("Lemon\nBanana\nPineapple") }}
```

Then, you can make the **".txt"** file with **a fruit name in each row**:

[image]